# SalesforceSharp No such column 'COMPLETEDDATETIME' on entity 'Task' error

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce, soql, salesforcesharp

Using SalesforceSharp in my app and running across this weird issue. I get the following error on a standard field "No such column 'COMPLETEDDATETIME' on entity 'Task'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

Have no problem pulling it up in a query on the dev console on Salesforce. I can export all Tasks using the DataLoader and it's there named the same! I know it's named COMPLETEDDATETIME and I have it included in the Task model. Anyone have ideas as to why it's throwing this error?

```
var recs = client.Query<Task>(@"SELECT COMPLETEDDATETIME
                                FROM Task");

// The model:
    public class Task {
    public DateTime COMPLETEDDATETIME { get; set; }
}

// Expecting to see:
2022-08-09T20:49:03.000Z
...
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the API version you're using when connecting to Salesforce, you'll see it in the URL you're using after successful login (whether it's soap or rest API implementation). This field is fairly new addition (winter 22 release I think) so API under 53 will struggle. I might be off by 1 but we're in 57 (stable) / 58 (summer preview) now.